# Knockout.js syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, javascript-framework

I am a beginner to the Javascript MVC framework Knockout.js

Coming from conventional Javascript (and some jQuery experience), I am having difficulties in understanding the syntax learning Knockout.js

Consider the statments below;

**The View:**

```
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
<li data-bind="text: $data, 
               css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
               click: $root.goToFolder"></li></ul>
```

**View Model:**

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { self.chosenFolderId(folder); };    
};
```

Could you please explain me what the statements do (specifically $data, $root) ?
Also what does the statement `self.chosenFolderId(folder);` does ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $data and $root keywords are typically used by KO.
When you use the foreach on array ( data-bind), KO creates one `<li>` for each element in the array.

In this case, $data is the current item of array (like folders[i]) and $root is the parent element.
For you, folders is a field of your ViewModel :
$data = current folders on the iteration (viewModel.folder[i])
$root = viewModel

self.chosendFolderId(folder) execute you viewModel chosenFolderId method. The code use self to keep the viewModel value because in the function the keyword "this" isn't the viewModel but the method's sender. It's a closure.

Edit : 
The $parent key word is the tree's previus level.
The $root key word is the top tree's level.

```
viewModel {
  topObjects : ko.observableArray()
}

viewModel.topObjects.push({
  Objects : ko.observableArray()
});
```

If we create a foreach on viewModel.topObjects.Objects, the $parent is topObjects, $root is viewModel.

Thanks Tjorriemorrie ;-)

Comment: Isn't $parent the parent and $root the root?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question about `self.chosenFolderId(folder)`

It writes value to `chosenFolderId` observable. The value of argument "`folder`" is actually current value of `$data.`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change reference from *self* to *this* ( which is the same thing) in the provided code , then the selection css doesn't work. Does anybody know why ?

```
this.goToFolder = function(folder) { this.chosenFolderId(folder); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question:

> what the statements do (specifically `$data`, `$root`) ?

`$data`: represents the current viewmodel. It's useful inside `foreach` loops. eg- if we have collection of students and we are iterating this collection, `$data` give us the current student instance. So that we can use `$data` to get the various properties of the student object like `name`, `class`, etc

`$root`: This is the root viewmodel, the highest context in the hierarchy. So through `$root`, you can get access to the top level properties.

Comment: Please add some formatting around code clips, it makes it much easier to read: e.g. `$data`