# What is root admin in knockout.js and what it points to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
data-bind="visible: $root.isAdministrator"
```

Can someone please explain what the above line means in `knockout.js`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout.js syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632767/knockout-js-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

`$root` is a variable that saves the root ViewModel. In this page there is anywhere defined a ViewModel like this:

```
var vm = {
  isAdministrator:ko.observable(true);
  aRootObserable:ko.observable("ROOT");
  childVm: {
    childObservable:ko.observable("CHILD");
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

It is used in knockout.js when the scope is on an underlying ViewModel but you want to access the root ViewModel. Example:

```
<div data-bind="with: childVm">
  <div data-bind="text: childObservable"><!-- result is CHILD --></div>
  <div data-bind="text: $root.aRootObserable"><! -- result is ROOT --></div>
</div>
```

If you are reengineering a knockout webpage you can search in all JS files for `applyBindings`. The parameter that is passed to this function is the root ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense